# Plasma-desktop starts using all the CPU time, on Mint linux 17. How to stop it

Tags: plasma

I'm using Mint linux 17, with KDE as my desktop manager.  Every so often my system really slows down, and I find that plasma-desktop is using 97-99% of cpu time (it's a dual core system).  I've tried killing it, and restarting it from a konsole (which is probably a really bad idea), but it sometimes works.
I know I could probably log-out and/or restart; but this is linux, and I shouldn't have to.